# Use stars for radio buttons in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I currently have a simple review form that goes out to people after a contractor does work on their home with questions on a scale from 1-10.  I'm using simple form and everything is working with the radio buttons.  I wanted to know if anyone has any good resources on making the radio buttons stars?  If not, what would be the best way to implement?  Here is the code I have for the form currently.

```
<div class="homeowner-questionnaire">
<%= simple_form_for @contractor_review, url: job_contractor_reviews_path(@job), html: { autocomplete: 'off' } do |f| %>
    <%= render partial: "layouts/validation_errors", object: @contractor_review %>
    <h4>Please rate the following based on a scale of 1 to 10, 1 being completey dissatisfied, and 1 being completely satisfied:</h4>
    <hr>
    <%= f.input :professionalism_and_organization, label: "Professionalism and Organization:", as: :radio_buttons, collection: (1..10).each %>
    <hr>
    <%= f.input :contractor_communication, label: "Contractor Communication:", as: :radio_buttons, collection: (1..10).each %>
    <hr>
    <%= f.input :problem_resolution, label: "Prolem Resolution:", as: :radio_buttons, collection: (1..10).each %>
    <hr>
    <%= f.input :convenience_of_scheduling, label: "Convenience of Scheduling:", as: :radio_buttons, collection: (1..10).each %>
    <hr>
    <%= f.input :construction_quality, label: "Construction Quality:", as: :radio_buttons, collection: (1..10).each %>
    <hr>
    <%= f.input :daily_jobsite_cleanliness, label: "Daily Jobsite Cleanliness:", as: :radio_buttons, collection: (1..10).each %>
    <hr>
    <%= f.input :overall_job_cleanup, label: "Overall Job Cleanup:", as: :radio_buttons, collection: (1..10).each %>
    <hr>
    <%= f.input :overall_installation_experience, label: "Overall Installation Experience:", as: :radio_buttons, collection: (1..10).each %>
    <hr>
    <%= f.input :overall_value_received, label: "Overall Value Received:", as: :radio_buttons, collection: (1..10).each %>
    <hr>  
    <%= f.input :overall_expectations, label: "Overall Expectations:", as: :radio_buttons, collection: (1..10).each %>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <%= f.input :areas_of_satisfaction, label: "Areas of Satisfaction:" %>
        <%= f.input :areas_for_improvement, label: "Areas for Improvement:" %>
        <%= f.input :recognized_individual_excellence, label: "Recognized Individual Excellence" %>
        <%= f.input :future_remodeling_needs, label: "Future Remodeling Needs:" %>
        <%= f.input :additional_comments, label: "Additional Comments:" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Are refactoring the radio buttons to stars the best approach or am I heading in the wrong direction?

Thanks in advance for the help, and let me know if there is anything else you would like to see.

Comment: You can probably do it with CSS.  As an example, see http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Comment: That's the route I was thinking.  I'd like to start with a CSS approach first, but I guess my issue is I'm not sure how to pass the right arguments to simple_form so it will render the HTML/CSS.  If that proves to be too much of a pain, I may go the jquery route.  Thanks for the link